# VS Code C program not run

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main(){
    system("cls");
    int k;
    // printf("Enter a Number: ");
    // scanf("%d",&n);

    for(int i = 1; i<=5;i++){
        k = 0;
        for(int j = 1 , k+=i; j<=5; j++){
            
            printf("%2d",k);
            k += 5;
            
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    getch();
}
```

this program in vs code not run but in turboo c this program run.In vs code give error:

```
error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '+=' token
         for(int j = 1 , k+=i; j<=5; j++){
```

This program in vs code not run, but in turbo c this program runs. In vs code it gives error:

```
error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '+=' token
         for(int j = 1 , k+=i; j<=5; j++){
```

Comment: Visual Studio Code doesn't run C programs. Are you seeing this as red-squigglies in the editor?

Comment: Also: <conio.h> is a non-standard header file. What platform are you compiling for? With which compiler?

Answer (score 2):

GCC fails with this:

```
foo.c:12:26: error: invalid '+=' at end of declaration; did you mean '='?
        for(int j = 1 , k+=i; j<=5; j++){
```

You can't use `+=` in the first part of the `for` statement.

It's expecting a variable declaration, and you've given it two:

```
int j = 1, k += i;
```

This declaration of `k` *hides* the previous one, and you're attempting to initialize it in terms of itself.

It's unclear from your question what you're expecting to do with `k`, but try `k = k + i` or just `k = i` instead. Or just initialize `k` on the line above.